# convert from triggered to continuous?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a web job that is triggered. I want to switch to continuous. I use ci/cd to deploy.

Is this the right steps :

1. csproj.  change triggered to continuous
2. settings.job just say {}

Also, I will change the c# host to use a loop with a sleep(xxx).

Am I missing anything?
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who use Visual Studio to develop and publish to Azure,

You may go in the Publish page and change the Webjob Type from Triggered to Continuous

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powershell CI/CD deploy to change the ***triggered*** to ***continuous*** and vice versa.

```
$deployUrl = "$($env:scmApiUrl)/zip/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/$($env:scheduleName)/$($env:webJobName)/"
```

Here you can add the `scheduleName` whether triggered or continuous

Follow the steps to achieve this [see here](https://dzone.com/articles/net-core-webjob-console-app-cicd-using-azure-devop)

More info [check here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-continuously-deploy-your-net-core-azure-web)

To manually change the [webjob type](https://azureappservices.blogspot.com/2019/09/update-or-change-webjobs-types-issue.html)